# Understanding output of cylinder function

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab's cylinder function i.e.
[X,Y,Z]=cylinder(radius);

But the values of X,Y,Z contain two rows.

Can someone please explain why two rows are coming. What does row=1 represents and what does row=2 represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complement @Eugene's answer, both rows do indeed correspond to the possible Z-positions of your data points. Since the radius does not vary with the cylinder's Z position, you only get 2 rows.

In the simple case where the radius is a constant, if you plot both rows separately you can see what they represent:

```
hFig = figure('Visible','off')

[x,y,z]=cylinder(5);

set(hFig,'Visible','on')
plot3(x(1,:),y(1,:),z(1,:))
hold on
plot3(x(2,:),y(2,:),z(2,:),'-r')
hold off
```

Giving this:

[image]

where both planes (i.e. z-positions) are of different colors.

However, let's consider the following, in which the cylinder's z-position is more complex:

```
t = 0:pi/10:2*pi;
figure
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(2+cos(t));
surf(X,Y,Z)
axis square
```

Then X,Y and Z will have 21 rows, corresponding to the possible Z-positions of the cylinder (i.e. `length(t) +1`):

[image]

Comment: +1. nice explanation. Although I would have reversed it. First showing what the 2 rows are, then extending to the other possibilities this arrangement of data brings.

Comment: yep you're right that makes much sense I'll edit my answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng! BTW we're having our first snowstorm here in QC City :)

Comment: Aha! We are too! It's coming down very heavily, but it's beautiful at the same time. Ferez-vous faire du ski!?

Comment: Yes it's beautiful! Unfortunately I won't be able to ski since I broke my ankle 2 weeks ago but I can't wait to recover!

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder surface is not a function, so each (X,Y) pair is corresponding to different Z values (in your case - 0 and 1). If you look at the value you are getting, you will notice that for X and Y you are getting the same data in both rows, for Z you will get different rows.

Comment: so you mean that if I have to output all the points I should do something like this:
point1: X(1,:),Y(1,:), Z(1,:)
point2: X(2,:),Y(2,:), Z(2,:)
but is this also valid
point3: X(1,:),Y(1,:), Z(2,:)

Comment: @RusheelJain Use the surf(X,Y,Z) function in order to visualize this data. This will help you understand the data as well.